# jQuery UI Selectmenu: customize button view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I know that there is an option to customize view of options by extending `_renderItem` function in selectmenu. Is there a way to place icon fo `buttonText` like in the following selectmenu options ?

[image: selectmenu]

I've searched through jquery examples, but didn't find the answer: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I found is that after selecting some option (`.ui-menu-item`) selectmenu calls `_setText` function, and passes `this.buttonText` element and and text from selected option e.g. something like `this.element.find('option:selected').text()`.

Maybe it's not a good way of designing widget, because as I understood, `_setText` called from multiple places always uses with `this.buttonText` element.

So to prevent overriding every method where `_setText` called I overrode `_setText` like:

```
_setText: function(element, value){
  if(element == this.buttonText){
    this._setButtonText();
  } else {
    this._superApply(element, value);
  }
},
_setButtonText: function(){
  // your logic
}
```